# Show image thumbnail and paragraph with summry

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm working with WordPress and can't seem to get the function I'm looking for. What I want to do is something similar to Smashing Magazine, where you show the first paragraph and image in the post on the home page. SM shows the second paragraph, but I won't need this.

I'm looking for something, ideally in `functions.php`, where I can limit this. So far, I've only seen a `CSS` approach like so where I display: none mo

Obviously this isn't the ideal solution, especially considering older browsers like `IE8` (which is as far back as I go).

I've tried techniques such as exploding the string, but that wasn't what I was looking for.

Any ideas, anyone ?

Comment: Why don't trying to edit the code instead of CSS change

Comment: I have set the reading options to show the excerpt. However, unless one is defined, it will show the whole post. I only want it to show the first paragraph and image, similar to how Smashing Magazine shows their latest posts.

Answer (score 1):

If you `can` edit the wordpress function system, then the function

- for the latest posts is: `wp_get_recent_posts( $args, $output )`
- for the thumbnail:  `get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr )`
- for the summary: `$excerpt = get_the_excerpt( $deprecated )`

if you believe that you `cannot` edit the code, then choose a plugin, such as: `special recent posts`, (there is also a given shortcode), edit your preference and enter it to the page that you need to.

Answer (score 0):

To show first paragraph you could use `Except`

**Reference : http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt**

```
   function excerpt_read_more_link($output) {
     global $post;
     return $output . '<a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> Read More...</a>';
    }
    add_filter('the_excerpt', 'excerpt_read_more_link');
```

**Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt**

and also could see  **`the_excerpt();`**

Control Excerpt Length using Filters

By default, excerpt length is set to 55 words. To change excerpt length using excerpt_length filter, add the following code to functions.php file in your theme:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```